# android 31+ "3 Button Navigation" Developer Option - how to enable programatically?

Tags: android, navigation, androidx, android-11, android-13

My application performs much better on Android 13 and 11 ( APIs 33 and 31 )
when the Settings->Developer
"3 Button Navigation" checkbox is Enabled - then a working Back button is enabled -
the Nokia XR20 device I am testing on lacks a "Back" or any Navigation buttons, so
hence there is no way to the "Context Menu" / Menus .

Would anyone know  / please could anyone suggest the best way to invoke this
Developer Settings dialog /
how to prompt User to make this settings change programatically ie. from Java or C++ code  ,
for an App to run on non-rooted devices ?

Ideally by sending some Intent to the Settings manager to launch that dialog ?

It is nasty when the user cannot interact with App to make Preferences changes & access menus
because there is no Menu / Back button on a device .

On https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings , there are hundreds
of ACTION_*_SETTINGS intents listed, with which, for Permissions and such, I can usually
create a PendingIntent to Launch the correct Settings Activity . But what is the correct
Settings Activity to launch the dialog for this developer option "3 Button Navigation Bar" mode ?

[image]

Comment: From a UX point of view, wouldn't it create a better experience if the app was adapted to the device and not the other way around?

Comment: Yes, thanks @Petra\ Minaler: that is precisely what I am trying to do,
adapt my App to install a working "Back Button" in the most efficient way ,
on phones such as Nokia XR20 which have no physical Navigation Buttons .

Comment: The most efficient / cleanest way to install  global "Up  |   HOME  |   Back/Menu" buttons
is with this "3 Button Navigation" Developer Option, it appears - if not, please suggest a better one - I am just trying to find out how to present a dialog where user can launch Settings Dialog to set "3 Button Navigation" in one click.

Comment: On the Nokia XR20, either out-of-the-box with Android 11 installed, 
or after System Upgrade to Android 13, 
If , having enabled Developer Options by clicking more than 3 times
on the Build Number in Phone Info, you then type "3" in the Settings Search bar,
the last line listed is then "App Info - 3 button Navigation Bar" -
I have that enabled and it fixed my app, as well as the whole phone UX for me -
but how to enable programmatically ?

Comment: I suppose I could send a Search intent to Settings, for "3", and then display a toast
saying "Please Select and Enable '3 Button Navigation Bar'" ? 
That will have to do , unless anyone can suggest a better idea ..

Comment: The above of course requires no code changes to app - ideally any solution 
would similarly not require any app code changes.

Of course, I can devote new screen real-estate (eg. lower right corner ) to a 
"Menu/Back" button , but this is kludgey & nasty in comparison to being able
to enable global 3-button-navigation-mode with a Settings change.

Comment: Aha, I think I need to send an Intent to the App Manager to show App-Info for the
"3 Button Navigation Bar" App , whatever its correct Package Name is ?

So the question becomes , what is the Package Name of that App ?
Then I can send an Intent direct to it ?